# distancia 0 entre un LinearLayout y un FloatingActionButton dentro de un Scrollview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Como puedo deja un LinearLayout y  FloatingActionButton dentro de un Scrollview sin distancia entre ellos. Por ejemplo convertir la imagen uno a la imagen dos

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> imagen 1
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> imagen 2

Codigo xml

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"

        android:background="@drawable/notInicio_1"
        android:orientation="vertical">










        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            app:backgroundTint="#CCFFFFFF"
            app:backgroundTintMode="src_in"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/xxxx"></android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>



    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Espero que se logre comprender mi duda, Gracias..

Comment: Muestra el código xml.

Comment: @David Hola, acabo de subir el codigo xml, Saludos!!

Comment: Solo necesitas eliminar los margenes del LinearLayout, android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
  android:layout_margin="15dp"

Answer (score 1):

En este caso puedes hacer dos cosas:

1- Elimina el margin del `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/notInicio_1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   ...

</LinearLayout>
```

2- Fuerza el `FloatingActionButton` para que se mueva mas a la izquierda, asignándole a su `layout_marginLeft` un valor negativo.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:backgroundTint="#CCFFFFFF"
    app:backgroundTintMode="src_in"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/xxxx"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
</android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>
```

Answer (score -2):

Es suficiente con eliminar el margen que tiene especificado el `LinearLayout`:

```
  android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
  android:layout_margin="15dp"
```

quedaría de esta forma:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"


    android:background="@drawable/notInicio_1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

El `FloatingActionButton`  se mostraría de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: -1 Por favor, ¿Algún comentario por el cual consideran esta respuesta incorrecta?